# onPress is called automatically while using NetInfo - react native

Tags: react-native

NetInfo is used to check the connection & theres a checkNetwork function called in onPress of TouchableOpacity. When the button is clicked once, the checkNetwork
function is called automatically multiple times without tapping the button when the network connection is lost and vice versa.

Please have a look at the code [here:](https://snack.expo.io/@codebyte99/networkissue)

Please have a look at the [video](https://youtu.be/ERPawrpcoq8)

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

  checkNetwork = () => {
    NetInfo.addEventListener((state) => {
      if (state.isConnected) {
        alert('isConnected');
      } else {
        alert('not connected');
      }
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              activeOpacity={0.8}
              onPress={()=> this.checkNetwork()}>
                <Text>Check here</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Because you are adding `eventListener` in this function body. What do you want to do at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not declare event listener inside of the click itself,

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {alert: ''};
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    NetInfo.addEventListener((state) =>  this.setState({ alert: state.isConnected ? 'isConnected' : 'not connected'})
 }
  checkNetwork = () => alert(this.state.alert)

  render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              activeOpacity={0.8}
              onPress={()=> this.checkNetwork()}>
                <Text>Check here</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

though in your case event listener isn't exactly the fit logic for UI behavior of pressing button, so I think you might wanna use `useNetInfo`

```
import {useNetInfo} from "@react-native-community/netinfo";


class App extends React.Component {
 checkNetwork = () => {
      if (this.props.netInfo.isConnected) {
        alert('isConnected');
      } else {
        alert('not connected');
      }
    });
  };

...rest render...
}

export default () => <App netInfo={useNetInfo()} />
```

Comment: tq Hagai Harari